# What microsoft.net version should I install after formating Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, format

I just formated my windows 7 and i have problem with microsoft.net because i moved the files from windows.old/microsoft.net to the new windows folder and it didn't work i also downloaded m.net v4.5 and installed it but it didnt run any m.net v4...i tried repair tool it didn't work i'm willing to delet all microsoft.net stuff and reinstall them again so can anyone tell me which version i need for windows 7 ? i mean all versions such 4, 4.5 pr 3.5 or 2 i had them all in my old windows...and please give me official links to do that.

Comment: Programs will install required versions of .NET during their installation. **Never "install" system components by copying files.** The same applies to majority of programs.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest installing the latest version (4.5 at this time) and then installing older versions as needed to run your software. Recent software should run fine but older software may require specific versions of .NET to be installed.

This page contains download links to most of the .NET frameworks you should need: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio/aa496123.aspx